# Is the set made up of all points that satisfy $g_{1}(x, y, z)=x^2 + 2y^2=1 $, $\:g_{2}(x, y, z)= xy + xz=2$ compact?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, compactness, maxima-minima

I want to find the least value of a function whose domain is made up of all points that satisfy the following:

$g_1(x, y, z)= x^2 + 2y^2=1$

$g_2(x, y, z)= xy + xz=2$

In my book it is written that "a minimum exists since the domain is a closed set". However, previously there is a theorem that one can only be certain that function obtains a max and min value if the domain is compact, i.e. both closed and bounded. From what I see, the domain is not bounded, how can we then be certain that "a minimum exists"?

Any help would be appreciated.

$\textbf{Edit:}$: I want to find the least distance form the origin, so my function is $f(x, y,z)=^2+^2+^2$

Comment: Did you know you could enclose entire expressions in dollar signs, and not just term-by-term? Much easier to type and looks better. Compare `$g_{1}$(x, y, z)= $x^2$ + 2$y^2$=1` $g_{1}$(x, y, z)= $x^2$ + 2$y^2$=1 to `$g_{1}(x, y, z)= x^2 + 2y^2=1$` $g_{1}(x, y, z)= x^2 + 2y^2=1$

Comment: Are you working in $\Bbb R^3$ or in $\Bbb C^3$?  I assume $\Bbb R^3$ but let's be sure.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you for informing me, I had never tried.

Comment: @Robert Shore Yes $\mathbb{R}^3$!

Comment: The answer has to depend on your particular function.  For example, if your function were $-z$, it would not even be bounded below.

Comment: @RobertShore I want to find the least distance form the origin, so my function is f(x, y,z)=$x^2+y^2+z^2$

Comment: @Pi314 See my answer.

Comment: @Robert Shore What is the domain???

Comment: @MatthewPilling The problem is to minimize the distance from the origin among all points satisfying the two equations in the problem.  Although the domain (the intersection of the two solutions sets) isn't compact, it's easy to see that the minimum must occur within a closed and bounded (and therefore compact) subset of the domain.

Comment: @Robert Shore The solution set to the two equations mentioned by the OP may be interpreted at the level set $g^{-1}(1,2)$ where $g=(g_1,g_2)$. If you restrict the domain of $g$ to a compact subset $C$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ then clearly $g^{-1}(1,2)\cap C$ is also compact. But, if we consider *all* possible solutions to this system, then this maximal solution set isn't bounded.

Comment: @MatthewPilling The question asks for a **minimal** solution, not a maximal solution.

Comment: My comment refers to a maximal **solution** **set**, not a minimum value of $x^2+y^2+z^2$. I should also note that my answer addresses the question of whether $g^{-1}(1,2)$ is compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (as was asked in the title of the post) not whether $x^2+y^2+z^2$ attains a minimum value on the domain $g^{-1}(1,2)$. If you want to find the smallest distance to the origin, just minimize $||\vec{r}(t)||$ on its maximal domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the additional information, set forth in your comment, that the function you're trying to minimize is $f(x, y, z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$, the solution is easy.  Just note that because $(1, 0, 2)$ is in your solution set, the minimum must fall within the (compact) sphere of radius, say, $953.8$ (or pick your favorite number that's at least as large as $\sqrt 5$).  Since the solution sets of $g_1$ and $g_2$ are closed, their intersection with this compact sphere must be compact and the minimum must occur somewhere in that intersection.

Comment: Right, thank you so much! I understand how I should reason now. Why did you pic the point (1, 0, 2), this point can be arbitrary as long as f(x, y, z) < $\sqrt 5$ right?

Comment: It was just the first point I could readily confirm was within your solution set.  Please feel free to upvote and accept answers you find useful.

Answer (score 3):

Take $g=(g_1,g_2):\mathbb{R}^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. Your set is clearly closed since $g$ is continuous and $$\{x^2+2y^2=1\}\cap\{xy+xz=2\}\cap \mathbb{R}^3=g^{-1}(1,2)$$ However, $g^{-1}(1,2)$ is not bounded. To see this, define $\vec{r}:A \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 $ by $$\vec{r}(t)=\bigg(\cos(t),\frac{\sin(t)}{\sqrt{2}},2\sec(t)-\frac{\sin(t)}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg)$$ where $A=\big[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\big)$. You can check that $\vec{r}(A)\subseteq g^{-1}(1,2)$. Moreover, $$||\vec{r}(t)||\geq \Bigg|2\sec(t)-\frac{\sin(t)}{\sqrt{2}}\Bigg|\rightarrow \infty$$ as $t\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}^{-}$ so $g^{-1}(1,2)$ isn't bounded.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just to be sure, $g^{-1}$ is that the intersection of the two sets made up of $g_{1}$ and $g_{1}$ or is it some sort of inverse? Also how did you know how to define the vector $\vec{r}$(t)?

Comment: The expression $g^{-1}(1,2)$ is the *preimage* of $(1,2)$ i.e. $$g^{-1}(1,2)=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : g(x,y,z)=(1,2)\}$$ Parameterizing a level set is a pretty standard approach for these kinds of problems. Think back to calculus when you had to find max/min of multivariable functions subject to a certain constraint